# Structure taking integer as value

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct parts {
    int partNumber;
    int partPrice;
} parts p;

void main() {
    cout << "Enter part number and its price " << endl;
    cin >> p.partNumber;
    cin >> p.partPrice;
    cout << "Part Number " << p.partNumber << "Part Price " << p.partPrice;
}
```

If I enter part number "098" and part price "3456", output is: `Part Number 98 Part Price 3456` Why is my input of "098" being output as "98"?

Comment: Why is your post formatted in this strange and unreadable way?

Answer (score 3):

Because the number you entered is `98`. That's the number above `97` and the number below `99`. A count. A quantity. An abstract concept.

An `int` is **NOT** a string of digits. It is not `'9'` followed by `'8'`, or `'0'` followed by `'9'` followed by `'8'`.

This makes complete sense when you think about how numbers are stored in the computer: in binary. Why would the computer, translating a decimal input into binary, separately store the number of leading zeroes you entered? That just isn't what it does, because there is no need for it.

I would generally recommend storing a "part number" as a string, because the "number" element is just what it's called in English and doesn't really accurately reveal what the value *is*: as you've indicated, you want it to be a string of characters. If nothing else, I routinely encounter "part numbers" with letters in them.

Comment: If i want to add then how shall i do it

Comment: @Rizvi: I do not understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

If leading zeros are meaningful, you should be storing your "numbers" as strings, not integers.  Your "numbers" aren't really numbers - the number `098` is the same as the number `98`, but the string `098` is different from the string `98`.